# Change background on selected item in listView

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I have problem when Im trying to change background on selected item in listview. When I select item A, it's background is changed. If I select item B, it changed too, but item A doesn't back to default background.

This drawable for background selected_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@color/colorMegna"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorWhite"/>
</selector>
```

This is the XML item_kategori.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lay_nama_kategori"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/selected_item">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView_kategori"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorMegna"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the setOnClickListener() in Adapter:

```
inner class CategoryViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    fun bind(kategori: Category){
            itemView.txtView_kategori.text = kategori.category
            itemView.setOnClickListener {

                if(kategoriList[adapterPosition] == kategori){
                    itemView.isSelected = true
                    itemView.txtView_kategori.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of which *ListItem* is selected.
In your Adapter class, create a variable that stores the current *ListItem*, which is selected

1. Create your variable `lastClicked`
2. In the constructor of the adapter, set that variable to -1, so that it doesn't point to anything
3. Whenever you click *ListItem* B, change the *lastClicked* *ListItem* (in this case it Item A) background to the original, then save the new *ListItem* (item B) position to `selectedItem` and change the background to show the newly clicked *ListItem*

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not setting the item A to its original color. When you click item B you need to d0 2 things. First, set the item B to the color you want and secondly set the item A back to its original color. Try this:

```
if(kategoriList[adapterPosition] == kategori){
      itemView.isSelected = true
      itemView.txtView_kategori.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
  } else {
      itemView.isSelected = false
      itemView.txtView_kategori.setTextColor(//any color you want)  
  }
notifydatasetChanged();
```